# Google Talk is blocked, even inside Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-talk, xmpp

is it possible to block Google Talk inside Gmail? I have a friend that experience this at work and I wonder if someone has advice on how he can contact me considering that the service is blocked.

Is there some other web interface for Google Talk or some Jabber akin service that would make it possible to chat with me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the IT dept is good then they won't leave any holes in their system because they obviously don't want him to do this activity.  There are a few typical work-arounds.

- Web service [Meebo.com](http://www.meebo.com/) (Likely this will be blocked as well)
- He could run
  [Pidgin](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/pidgin_portable)
  IM client from a portable drive.
- He could use a smartphone app.

The latter is probably the least risky.